# Mount drive at /Volumes/NAME/ or similar in Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, mount, usb-storage

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7. When I plug in an USB stick, the drive automatically gets mounted to /cygdrive/x . This is good and really easy to use.

My problem is that the drive letter changes sometimes, and when I've got remotes set up in git - I've got one called usb at /cygdrive/h/ - this sometimes doesn't work and I have to change the remote URL. That's just an example, there are other scenarios where I wouldn't want it to change.

I like what the Mac does, and puts mounts a volume at /Volumes/STICK (STICK is the Volume name of my usb stick). Is there any way I can do this, or something similar under Cygwin.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [USB Drive Letter Manager](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) to [mount your thumbdrives to a NTFS folder](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm458_help_e.html#ntfs_folders) using the drive's label.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I have found that if you explicitly set a drive letter in Disk Management  (Start->Programs->Administrative Tools->Computer Management-->Disk Management) it will 'try' to remount at the same letter every time. I usually pick a mid-aphabet letter, like L: or N:, so that the likelihood of an auto-mount using that letter is minimized.